# Pegar o valor de um input e escrevê-lo em uma tag <H1>

Tags: javascript, html

Minha ideia é a seguinte: Mostrar uma tela ao usuário e pedir a ele seu nome. Depois que ele clicar no botão de submit, **quero fazer o nome dele aparecer em uma tag .**

Link de uma imagem explicando melhor: https://photos.app.goo.gl/FV9m4Cn4cguURAMv8

Código inteiro (html, css, js):

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sem Importância</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #222;
    }


    .hey-container.close {
      transform: translateX(-993px);
      transition: 2s;
    }

    .hey-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 40px;
      padding: 20px;
      max-width: 600px;
      background-color: #7654dc;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px #222;
      transition: 4s;
    }

    .hey-container input {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
      background-color: #62209f;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      font-style: italic;
      display: none;
    }

    .hey-container input.showInput {
      display: block;
    }

    .hey-container h1 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #222;
    }

    .hey-container .buttons button {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 12px;
      background-color: #62209f;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hey-container .buttons button:hover {
      background-color: #4c1a7a;
    }

    .hey-container .buttons button.noOption {
      color: #bebebe;
    }

    .buttons {
      display: flex;
      gap: 40px;
    }

    .yesOption.closeButtons {
      display: none;
    }
    .noOption.closeButtons {
      display: none;
    }

    .submitButton {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 12px;
      background-color: #62209f;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }

    .submitButton.showSubmit {
      display: block;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="hey-container">
    <h1>Hey! Could you tell me your name?</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="noOption">No!</button>
        <button class="yesOption">Sure!</button>
        <form style="display: flex; gap: 20px;">
          <input type="text" required placeholder="text here...">
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">That's my name!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


  <script>

    const noButton = document.querySelector('.noOption');
    const yesButton = document.querySelector('.yesOption');
    const divQuest = document.querySelector('.hey-container');
    const submitBUTTON = document.querySelector('.submitButton');
    const inputName = document.querySelector('input');

    function closeQuest() {
      divQuest.classList.add('close');
    }

    function openInput() {
      inputName.classList.add('showInput');
      submitBUTTON.classList.add('showSubmit')
      yesButton.classList.add('closeButtons');
      noButton.classList.add('closeButtons');
    }

    noButton.addEventListener('click', closeQuest);
    yesButton.addEventListener('click', openInput);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4):

Adicione um retorno no `form`, e um `id` no `input` e no `h1`:

```
<h1 id="titleName">Hey! Could you tell me your name?</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="noOption">No!</button>
      <button class="yesOption">Sure!</button>
      <form style="display: flex; gap: 20px;" onsubmit="return showName();">
        <input id="userName" type="text" required placeholder="text here...">
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">That's my name!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Altere o `h1` de na função:

```
function showName() {
      const input = document.querySelector('#userName');
      let name = input.value
      const title = document.querySelector('#titleName');
      title.textContent = 'Hello '+name+'!'
      return false
    }
```